# excel VBA End method on Range object -- application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm experiencing an error with using the End method of the range object.

The code below is an excerpt from my program, and when I get to the last line I get the following error: "Application defined or Object Defined error"

```
Sub DataGroup(testCell, j, k)
    Dim archive As Range
    Set dataCellsA = Worksheets("DATA").Range("B2")
    Set dataCellsB = Worksheets("DATA").Range("I2")
    For i = 0 To 30
        Set currentLine = testCell.Offset(i, 0)
        Set archive = Worksheets("ARCHIVE").Range("B4").End(x1Down)
```

However, in a later portion of my program I have what appears to be the same implementation, but I don't receive any errors with this portion.

```
    Set dataCellsA = Worksheets("DATA").Range("C2")
    Set dataCellsB = Worksheets("DATA").Range("J2")

    Dim lastCellA As Range
    Dim lastCellB As Range

    Set lastCellA = dataCellsA.End(xlDown)
    Set lastCellB = dataCellsB.End(xlDown)
```

Whats the difference between the two? I'm making sure to declare my variables as ranges, and I'm careful to use the "Set" prefex to ensure that it is an object, and not the value.

Comment: Is "ARCHIVE" correctly spelled? And is it in the same workbook as the code?

Comment: I see `x1Down` where you should have `xlDown`!!

Comment: And beware: x1Down is not xlDown (very slight difference)

Comment: @KazJaw care to change it into an answer and get this question "resolved"?

Comment: @KazJaw Oh wow.. thanks for that one. I would have never noticed such a small detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here is the answer: you have `x1Down` where you should have `xlDown` (1 instead of l)